# How to read CSV files in chunks and run function for every chunk in JS/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to read CSV/TSV files in Node/JS and run a function at certain intervals.

For example, I want to get 10,000 lines in list, then run a function with this 10,000 lines without continue to read the file. When function is done working, continue to next 10,000 lines and do the same until the end.

How can I do that?

I manage to stream the file and also run the function at every 10,000 lines but I guess script runs async so it runs all the function all almost at the same time.

#### My solution so far

```
fs.createReadStream(file_path)
  .pipe(csv({ separator: '\t' }))
  .on('data', (row) => push_to_list(row)  // <-- stream should wait for func
  )
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log("DONE");
  })
```

Comment: I suggest you to edit your answer posting what you've tried so far

Comment: I would also consider looking at a generator function that emits the 10k lines per step

Comment: @Nick thanks for that. I edited with my primitive solution :D

Comment: @akaphenom I stream lines and add them to list with function. When list hits 10K, I call an API. 10K is not special, I just can't call API at every single line. It crashes. So I need to wait for API to finish, and then continue to next 10K.

Comment: I woulk look at these two links and combine for ananswer: https://stackabuse.com/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-node-js/
 AND 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

essentially build an array fo up to 10k lines inside of the function* and then "yield" it out. call it by `for chunk of getChunks() {  }` where getchunks is function*

Comment: please post sample input and then sample output (or what you will pass to the function that makes the API call)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is ideal but you could accomplish this by pushing the row to an array and then calling the function when it hits 10k rows. At the end if there's anything in the rows array you can call the function with the remaining rows < 10k.

```
let rows = []
fs.createReadStream(file_path)
  .pipe(csv({ separator: '\t' }))
  .on('data', (row) => {
    rows.push(row)
    if (rows.length === 10000) {
      push_to_list(rows) // <-- stream should wait for func
      rows = []
    }
  }
  )
  .on('end', () => {
    if (rows.length) {
      push_to_list(rows)
    }
    console.log('DONE')
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this still continues regardless of `push_to_list` function is done. Non-stop calling the function at every 10K, instead of waiting for function to finish

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking something like this:

```
// getChunk reads the file and pushes things into a lines array
function* getChunk(){
  let lines = []
  lineReader.open('/path/to/file', function(reader) {

    if (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        reader.nextLine(function(line) {
            lines.push(line);
            // when the lines are large enough, pause and emit the results, and reset the array
            if (lines.length == 10000) {
              yield lines;
              lines = []
            }
        });
    }
   }); 

   // last odd sized chunk
   yield lines 
};

// each chunk is an array of 10k lines, because of the generator funciton (function*) we can use iterator syntax
for (const chunk of getChunks()) {
  console.log(o);
}
```

From an engienering and code structure perspective this leaves a lot of work to be done (don't open the file inside of the generator, maybe parametize the chunk size too, clean up the file handle).  but this is a great fit for generator functions

Comment: is `if (lines.length == 10000)` supposed to return a last chunk if the overall number of results is for example 12.000? you will get a chunk of 10.000 but the other will be of 2.000 only

Comment: I am doing this in between meetings - see edit (BTW you are 100% right :))

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I couldn't get it to work. This doesn't deal with CSV data and if I try to convert my existing function with `fs.createReadStream`, I get `Unexpected strict mode reserved word` for `yield`. Man, this is super easy to do in Python, why is it so painful with JS? :(

Comment: @stackyname post a version of the input dn a version of the output if you want more of a hand.  I am failry confident this is the blueprint for an answer for you.  The asynch by default operating model can present some challenges

Comment: @akaphenom Sure, I can provide that but I discovered that `yield` cannot be used in inner function. That's why the script above doesn't work. I just can't figure out how to yield from a stream.

Comment: right. generator functions (function *) are different than regular functions. they are not interchangable. You need to structure similar to my code - your objection is that the sample I posted is treating the CSV (it isn't) - but it could, right before you `lines.push(line)`

Comment: @stackyname did you ever manage to get this working? I'm suffering from the same problem and coming from a Python background this is ridiculously difficult.

Comment: @martinkaburu Unfortunately, no. I've never tried again. I always use Python as much as I can.